# PHP handled CSV not generating in linux environment

Tags: php, linux, csv

hi im currently using a script which generates csv and sends its download link(destination) in a email. in the following code,the email is sent correctly but it does not generate the csv.

**Code**

```
$fileD = "Weekly_Report_From_".date('d-m-Y', strtotime('-1 week'))."_to_".date('d-m-Y').".csv";
$url_down = (Config_Reader::readProjectConfig('report')->exportDirectory.'/weeklyReport/'.$fileD);
echo "<br/>";
echo $url_down;

if(file_exists($url_down) == false){
    echo "FILE DOES NOT EXISTs";
 $fp = fopen($url_down, 'w');
$header = array("XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX");
fputcsv($fp, $header, ',');
foreach ($tables as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields,',');
} 
}
else{   echo "FILE EXISTs";
    $time_start = time();
    $fileD = "Weekly_Report_From_".date('d-m-Y', strtotime('-1 week'))."_to_".date('d-m-Y')."#".$time_start.".csv";
    $url_down = (Config_Reader::readProjectConfig('report')->exportDirectory.'/weeklyReport/'.$fileD);
        $fp = fopen($url_down, 'w');
        $header = array("XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX","XX");
        fputcsv($fp, $header, ',');
        foreach ($tables as $fields) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fields,',');
        } 
}
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
fclose($fp);

$mail = new Zend_Mail ();
$sentFromEmail = $config->sentFrom_new;
$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail ( '-f' . $sentFromEmail );
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport ( $tr );
$mail->setReturnPath($sentFromEmail);
$mail->setFrom ( $sentFromEmail, 'Reporters' );
$rty = "Hi,<br /><br />This system is working perfectly <a href=".$url_down.">Report</a>.";
$mail->setBodyHtml ( $rty );
$mail->addTo ( $weeklyReportRecipients );
$mail->setSubject ( "Weekly Report" );


try {
    $mail->send ();
    echo "success";
}
```

when i go in more detail. it always prints the file does not exist which is correct but it never makes the csv inside the directory,

I allowed all read write and excute permissions to the weeklyReport folder as well, but still no luck,, will any body be able to help me over this...

P.S $tables is the array that take use of to generate the csv... that works fine. and also $weeklyReportRecipients, $sentFromEmail are obtained from the config file and they are also working fine

Comment: anybody have an idea about this issue

Comment: can you write any file there `file_put_contents('<path/file>','test');`? also enable error_reporting and watch out for open_basedir

Comment: i have enable error reporting but doesnt show anything

Comment: Hmm, this smells like a permission problem. Who's the owner of the directory where the file should be generated, is it the same user as the webserver process owner, is the directory writable for that user? Try on the Linux environment the following: log in as the Apache user (www-data or whatever it is on your system) and create a file in the right directory. If that works, then disregard this comment ;-)